# How can I tell if an IEnumerable has been evaluated?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, iqueryable

Can I know whether the deferred evaluation of an `IEnumerable` (or `IQueryable`) has already happened? That is, whether `GetEnumerator().MoveNext()` has ever been called. Is there a way?

How would I code `HasBeenEvaluated()` in the following example?

```
private void Example()
{
    IEnumerable<Thing> things = _Repository.GetObjects<Thing>();

    bool x = HasBeenEvaluated(things); // returns false

    foreach (var thing in things)
    {
         x = HasBeenEvaluated(things); // returns true
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518859/how-to-determine-if-an-ienumerable-has-been-evaluated

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624805/is-it-possible-to-determine-if-an-ienumerablet-has-deffered-execution-pending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper for an `IEnumerable` that, when iterated, flips a boolean to indicate that it has been iterated:

```
//TODO come up with a better name
public class Foo<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private IEnumerable<T> wrapped;
    public Foo(IEnumerable<T> wrapped)
    {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }
    public bool HasBeenIterated { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        HasBeenIterated = true;
        foreach (var item in wrapped)
            yield return item;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Your method can now become:

```
private void Example()
{
    var things = new Foo<Thing>(_Repository.GetObjects<Thing>());

    bool x = things.HasBeenIterated;//is false

    foreach (var thing in things)
    {
        x = things.HasBeenIterated;//is true
    }
}
```

Comment: The original motivation for the question was that I was trying to write a unit test to ensure the evaluation wasn't happening early. This fits the bill.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. The interface `IEnumerable<>` does not support that.

Also, if you have an `IEnumerator<>`, you cannot tell in general if `MoveNext()` was ever called.

Sometimes an `IEnumerator<>` will support the `Reset()` method, but this is not what you ask. Many enumerators will just throw an exception when you try to `Reset()`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can inherit from the type and add a method to it to return the state.

In this case you would add a property to this class that would reflect the state of an operation being called.

```
public class StatefulThings : IEnumerable<Thing>
{
  bool _moveNextExecuted = false;

  public override bool MoveNext()
   {
      // Perform next pointer

      // Set state of hasBeenEnumerated in here...
      _moveNextExecuted  = true;
   }
}
```